# Keeping a Character Controller grounded?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I've got a character that makes use of `isGrounded()` to determine whether I can jump, whether my air-jump is reset, and the amount of friction to be applied. I've run into a common problem, `isGrounded()` is fluctuating every frame returning true and false randomly resulting in jagged movement.

The standard suggestion is to constantly apply gravity. Unfortunately, aside from any other more nuanced issues that this could result in, this only works for me if I apply so much gravity that I am no longer able to climb up slopes. I need a way to keep the character grounded without applying large amounts of gravity every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common cause of this problem is using the Physics resolver for determining if a character is grounded. The issue arises because the physics solver's whole purpose is to push your character and the ground apart (so they aren't inter-penetrating).

Tricks like increasing gravity work by attempting to force the character back into the ground each frame. This isn't very reliable, as you've mentioned, and increases the work of the physics engine and decreases physics stability.

Some physics engines can further attempt to resolve this problem using things like separation slop (which means the objects aren't *completely* pushed apart) or by maintaining a contact cache. Using these features to solve the gound detection problem can require some extra work, though; the results of testing for sloppy collision or querying the contact cache may require the use of different APIs or events than what you're currently using. I'm not super familiar with Unity physics so I can't provide any specific insight for your case.

A very generalized solution that works for almost engine is to use a separate means of detecting the ground which doesn't directly rely on your character's physics body. These can include short ray casts (e.g., shoot some rays down about 1/5th of a unit or so from the corners and center of the character's feet) to probe for the ground, or using a thin physics sensor (or several sensors) attached to the character's feet. These methods don't try to test if the character is touching the ground but instead test if the character is *really close* to the ground. It sounds hacky but works phenomenally well.

Using multiple rays or multiple sensors can also help you detect some interesting scenarios that the simpler physics-collision method has trouble with. For instance, if you want to detect if a character is standing on a ledge, the use of multiple rays or sensors can indicate this clearly (e.g. the left sensor indicates there's ground but the right sensor does not, thus the character is standing on a ledge).

Using several rays or sensors of increased height can supply further information. For instance, short rays might detect if the character is *very* near to ground (close enough that you can consider them grounded) while some slightly longer rays can indicate that the character is near ground. This can be used to inform animation, to control game features like double jump, or to help keep characters grounded when running down ramps (if the character was grounded and the next frame - no jumping involved - the character is only very near the ground, snap the character back down to the ground).

Physics engines and platformers aren't a good fit for each other. You have to muck around behind the physics engine's back using techniques like I've described to achieve that ideal Nintendo-like feel to your characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems and realized my character's animation was causing the fluctuation because I had both the physics engine and an animation moving my character.

My solution was to avoid collider collision detection as my means of ground detection. Instead I use ray casting. See this answer here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/575637/ground-detection.html

For my character I use three rays and perform a count. If at least two rays hit the floor I consider my character grounded.

[image: ray cast example]

Comment: I wouldn't use the center point for the rays as that can result in some weird cases like the character being considered "grounded" when it's falling down a very narrow vertical tunnel. The rays should all be aligned to the Y axis to be sure that you're only looking for actual ground beneath the character's feet. If you also need detection of horizontal nearby surfaces then there should be some additional X-axis-aligned rays for specifically that purpose.

Comment: funny enough, my screenshot is kind of bad because I did do exactly what you are describing. My ray for detection goes between the "Ray_Start" and "Ray_End" to detect the floor under the character. The rays from the center are debug drawn rays and from the center location did pose some issues with certain situations.